# Android - verify the signature of XML

Tags: android, xml

I have signed XML document (by pure Java with RSA and X509 tags) on the web and I have implemented XML pull parser - before I parse some information from my XML document to specific URL, I need to verify this document if it is the right one. Do you know how to check XML signature?

Thanks

edit:

my XML file looks like follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
  <application id="1">
  <appversion>1.0</appversion> 
  <obligatory>yes</obligatory> 
  <update>http://www.xyz.....</update> 
  <check>http://www.xyz.....</check> 
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" /> 
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /> 
      <ds:Reference URI="#1">
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /> 
        <ds:DigestValue>fuv...</ds:DigestValue> 
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue>PC0+4uO4...</ds:SignatureValue> 
  <ds:KeyInfo>
  <ds:KeyValue>
    <ds:RSAKeyValue>
      <ds:Modulus>gEs/Fn2Gd5evwhlUgoS3...</ds:Modulus> 
      <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent> 
    </ds:RSAKeyValue>
  </ds:KeyValue>
  <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
      <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=abc abc,OU=abcs,O=abc,L=abc,ST=abc,C=abc</ds:X509IssuerName> 
      <ds:X509SerialNumber>123456...</ds:X509SerialNumber> 
    </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
    <ds:X509SubjectName>CN=abc abc,OU=abcs,O=abc,L=abc,ST=abc,C=abc</ds:X509SubjectName> 
    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDhzCCAm+gAwIBAgI...</ds:X509Certificate> 
  </ds:X509Data>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
```

Comment: I've not looked into this too much, but the http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html API might help

Comment: I think it is not included in Android SDK :-(

Comment: No, but it is a 3rd party Java library you should be able to use with your app.

Comment: but how to add it into my projects? I have seen many questions over internet and noone was able to answer it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In J2EE Java you would use `javax.xml.crypto` as detailed here

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/dig_signature_api/

However these are not part of the standard Android package.

It *may* be a manageable amount of work to make your own package of the bits of the source you need.

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#-WpwJU0UKqQ/src/share/classes/javax/xml/crypto/dom/DOMCryptoContext.java&d=5

Comment: Yea, I was stunned when I realised that XML signature is not present from J2EE... and don't you see any other way?

Comment: The second link is broken

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Santuario but you need to strip it down. Look at https://web.archive.org/web/20140902223147/http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1302/ for more details.

Comment: have you more details on how it could be used?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following stripped version of Apache Santuario with the XML security features: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/2.0.2

Then you just need to create some verifier class, for example:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

import org.apache.xml.security.keys.KeyInfo;
import org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature;
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants;
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils;

enter code here

public class Whatever {
    boolean verifySignature() {
    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        // parse the XML
        InputStream in = obtainInputStreamToXMLSomehow();
        DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        f.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = f.newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
        in.close();

        // verify signature
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, "Signature");
        if (nodes.getLength() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Signature NOT found!");
        }

        Element sigElement = (Element) nodes.item(0);
        XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(sigElement, "");

        KeyInfo ki = signature.getKeyInfo();
        if (ki == null) {
        throw new Exception("Did not find KeyInfo");
        }

        X509Certificate cert = signature.getKeyInfo().getX509Certificate();
        if (cert == null) {
        PublicKey pk = signature.getKeyInfo().getPublicKey();
        if (pk == null) {
            throw new Exception("Did not find Certificate or Public Key");
        }
        valid = signature.checkSignatureValue(pk);
        }
        else {
        valid = signature.checkSignatureValue(cert);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return valid;
    }

    // This is important!
    static {
    org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Seems like including XML parsing libraries in Android is trickier than expected. First you need to generate the jar file and then modify some of the library namespaces (using JarJar tool). After that, add it to the project's library directory (/lib or /libs). [Source](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/SiriRestClient/wiki/Modifying-XML-libraries-for-Android)

I switched from signed XML to Signed JSON (RFC 7515)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Apache Santuario. http://santuario.apache.org/

Comment: The current (1.4.4) version of santuario is 5.5MB, and that is a lot if you plan to include it in android application.