# Sign XML with x.509 android

Tags: android, xml, certificate, signature, x509

Is there any way to sign Xml document with X.509?
I've been looking all over internet but it seems that signing xml document with x.509 is not possible?.

```
 <Signaturexmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
 <SignedInfo>
 <CanonicalizationMethodAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 <SignatureMethodAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
 <ReferenceURI="#nana">
 <Transforms>
 <TransformAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
 <TransformAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 </Transforms>
 <DigestMethodAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
 <DigestValue>VItfxY/A1BITZ/BuWpsGd9gKix4=</DigestValue>
 </Reference>
 </SignedInfo>

  <SignatureValue>0+5U........ many numbers and character.....
 </SignatureValue>
 <KeyInfo>
 <X509Data>
 <X509Certificate>MIIEyDCCA7CgAwIBAgIEPssQ2TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADArMQswCQYDVQQGEwJI
 UjENMAsGA1UEChMERklOQTENMAsGA1UECxMEREVNTzAeFw0xMjA5MjcxMDQ5MThaFw0xNDA5Mjc
  xMTE5MThaMFkxCGjB623/kdW
  .......
 </X509Certificate>
 <X509IssuerSerial>
 <X509IssuerName>blablabla</X509IssuerName>
 <X509SerialNumber>1054324313</X509SerialNumber>
 </X509IssuerSerial>
 </X509Data>
 </KeyInfo>
 </Signature>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java edition of our SecureBlackbox product ([XMLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-xml.php) package) for full scope of XML signing operations.

Also you can find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769142/android-verify-the-signature-of-xml) useful. In that question signature validation (not signing) is discussed, but maybe you can make use of that suggestions as well.

Comment: thank you, as soon as I try it i'll let you know how it went.

Comment: this is quite usefull, but i don't have money for licence and my app will be for selling, but thank you for link!